# Solr - How to match NGram enforcing position

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet

Suppose I have the following field stored in a document in Solr:

ABCDEFG

First I want to split it to NGrams with size 3 (ABC, BCD, CDE etc..) I did this by declaring:

```
 </fieldType>
    <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TriGramField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="3" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

My problem is that I want to match my queries based on position.
Meaning:

EFGABC should not get a high score as 'EFG'/ 'ABC' NGrams are not in the correct position and therefore should not be considered as a match ['EFG' in the original string is in position 5 and not in position 1]

Any idea how can I achieve this?